# Observable return type must be parameterized as Observable<Foo> or Observable<? extends Foo>

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using retrofit 2.0.0-beta2 and debug build is working properly but I'm getting the following error on release build with Proguard.

Here's the updated logcat errors.

```
11-17 18:23:22.751 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime: Process: ph.reggis.FEDT, PID: 16274
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ph.reggis.FEDT/ph.reggis.FEDT.view.activity.NotificationListActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class b.a
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     for method InsularFMService.getNews
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for class b.a
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     for method InsularFMService.getNews
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at retrofit.Utils.methodError(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at retrofit.MethodHandler.createCallAdapter(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at retrofit.MethodHandler.create(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at retrofit.Retrofit.loadMethodHandler(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at retrofit.Retrofit$1.invoke(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at $Proxy0.getNews(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at ph.reggis.FEDT.b.C.d(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at ph.reggis.FEDT.view.fragment.NotificationListFragment.t(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at ph.reggis.FEDT.view.fragment.NotificationListFragment.l(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.b.B.a(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.b.B.a(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.b.B.a(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.b.B.i(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.b.y.i(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.b.t.onPostResume(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.a.B.onPostResume(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6336)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Observable return type must be parameterized as Observable<Foo> or Observable<? extends Foo>
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.get(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at retrofit.Retrofit.nextCallAdapter(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:     at retrofit.Retrofit.callAdapter(Unknown Source)
11-17 18:23:22.752 16274-16274/ph.reggis.FEDT E/AndroidRuntime:         ... 28 more
```

Interface:

```
@GET("news")
Observable<News> getNews();
```

Fragment:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constant.WS_URL_BASE)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();

InsularFMService fmService = retrofit.create(InsularFMService.class);

//Observable<News> observable = fmService.getNews();
//subscription = observable. - ALSO NOT WORKING

subscription = fmService.getNews().
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(appController.getDefaultScheduler())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<News>() {...
```

Graddle:

```
compile "com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2"
```

Proguard:

```
# Fixed: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field producerIndex
 -keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
     long producerIndex;
     long consumerIndex;
 }
 -keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
     long producerNode;
     long consumerNode;
}
```

Comment: already added the full logcat. Thanks Arthur :)

Comment: Got it already. I just specified the Gson attributes and annotations inside the Proguard.

Comment: @Marvs if you found a solution, please add it as an answer so you can help other people with similar problems.

Comment: @Splatters already posted the solution. Thanks

Comment: In my case it was a java version issue. Retro fit requires java 1.7 so be aware you should also compile with 1.7 by adding the following lines to build.gradle     compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now it's working by putting these attributes inside the Proguard.

```
# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class ph.reggis.FEDT.model.api.** { *; }
```

Here's the full settings

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class ph.reggis.FEDT.model.api.** { *; }

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Answer (score 2):

this problem happened to me after migrating to android studio flamingo. The solution for me was to add the necessary settings for the gson library to the proguard-rules.pro file. I got this solution from a person named Chirag Thummar who responded to a discussion about this on github.
I was able to run the apk release version only on these settings and ***agp 7.3.1***
answer link: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3751#issuecomment-1525914941
codes:

```
 ##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { <fields>; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapter, TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.TypeAdapter
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

# Prevent R8 from leaving Data object members always null
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}


-keep class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep public class * implements java.lang.reflect.Type


# Retain generic signatures of TypeToken and its subclasses with R8 version 3.0 and higher.
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class * extends com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```